# Calculating Champernowne constant C10 using Boost

Tags: c++, math, boost, arbitrary-precision

I am attempting to calculate the [Champernowne constant C10](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChampernowneConstant.html) using the following formula:

[image: C_b=sum_(n=1)^inftyn/(b^(n+sum_(k=1)^(n)|_log_bk_|))]

In the above formula, I substitute *b* for 10 to calculate C10. I want to be able to calculate the constant to any precision using Boost's `cpp_dec_float`.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>

const long long PRECISION = 100;

typedef boost::multiprecision::number<
    boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<PRECISION> > arbFloat;

arbFloat champernowne()
{
    arbFloat c, sub, n, k;
    std::string precomp_c, postcomp_c;

    for(n = 1; n == 1 || precomp_c != postcomp_c; ++n) {
        for(k = 1; k <= n; ++k) {
            sub += floor(log10(k));
        }

        precomp_c = static_cast<std::string>(c);
        c += n / pow(10, n + sub);
        postcomp_c = static_cast<std::string>(c);
    }

    return c;
}
```

Here's a breakdown of the code:

1. I begin by defining a variable `arbFloat` which has a precision of 100 digits (this is changed often — so I don't want to use `cpp_dec_float_100`).
2. The formula has two blocks of summation, so I implement them using two for-loops. In the innermost for-loop I calculate the summation beginning with `k = 1` conditional upon `k <= n` for `floor(log10(k))`.

**I have verified that using `floor()` and `log10()` on `cpp_dec_float` returns variables with correct precision.**

3. Because the outermost summation goes until infinity, I have to stop calculations at some point. To check whether the precision has been exceeded, I cast `c` to a string before I calculate `c += n / pow(10, n + sub)` - and then I cast it to a string after I do the calculation. If the strings are the same, I end the calculations because the precision has been exceeded (further calculations would be redundant).

**I have also used this set up (with string casting and comparison to check exceeded precision) to calculate other variables - and it works very well.**

4. Next I calculate the outermost summation of `c += n / pow(10, n + sub)` - using `pow()` in this manner *does* maintain the precision. Finally, I return `c`.

When I run this program, I get the following variable:

```
0.1234567891001100120001300001400000150000001600000001700000000180000000001900000000002000000000000210
```

vs. the *real* Champernowne constant C10:

```
0.1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253546
```

Only the first 11 digits are correct, and the rest are not. I am not able to find where I am going wrong. I have tried the following:

- Tried replacing `c += n / pow(10, n + sub)` with `c += n / pow(static_cast<arbFloat>(10), n + sub)` to check if `pow()` was not maintaining precision - but it didn't change anything.
- Tried replacing `floor()` with a method of casting `log10(k)` to a string and "rounding" the string (keep only characters before `.`) - but it didn't change anything.
- Tried changing `k <= n` to `k < n`, `k <= n + 1` - just in case I was misinterpreting the summation - but that only made it more inaccurate.

If I need to explain more, let me know. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The previous value of `sub` is being carried forward on each iteration; declare it inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous value of sub is being carried forward on each iteration; declare it inside the loop.

```
arbFloat champernowne() {
    arbFloat c;

    for (int n = 1;; ++n) {
        arbFloat sub;

        for (int k = 1; k <= n; ++k) {
            sub += floor(log10(k));
        }

        arbFloat const last = c;
        c += n / pow(10, n + sub);

        if (c == last) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Using your implementation for determining exceeded precision also improved the performance of my program: from ~33 seconds to **0.957 seconds**! Thank you!